# How to transform LiveData<List<Entity>> to LiveData<List<Date>>

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-livedata-transformations

My project is an expense tracker where I show a list of Dates under which I have a list of expenses that happened on those dates. I have nested RecyclerViews. Parent RecyclerView is a list of unique dates of all expenses. Child RecyclerView is list of expenses (viewed, of course, under unique dates).
My ViewModel has a list of LiveData of ExpenseEntity. The ViewModel has to have a list of LiveData of Date which contains unique dates. I get my list of ExpenseEntity from a Room database.

My main fragments observes the LiveData of ExpenseEntities because then is when I need to update my parent and child recyclerviews.

I cannot figure out how to use Transformations.map to have a live transforming list of unique dates. How should I make sure the LiveData of Dates is always updated once LiveData of ExpenseEntity is updated?

**MainActivityViewModel.kt**

```
class MainActivityViewModel(private val expenseDao: ExpenseDao) : ViewModel() {
    val allExpenses : LiveData<List<ExpenseEntity>> = expenseDao.fetchAllExpenses().asLiveData()
    val uniqueDates : LiveData<List<Date>> = Transformations.map(allExpenses) {
        it.map { expense ->
            expense.date!!
        }.distinct()
    }
...
}
```

**ExpensesFragment.kt**

```
val factory = MainActivityViewModelFactory((activity?.application as SimpleExpenseTrackerApp).db.expenseDao())
expensesViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)


binding.rvParentExpenseDates.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
expensesViewModel.allExpenses.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ expensesList ->
    if (expensesList.isNotEmpty()){
       binding.rvParentExpenseDates.adapter = expensesViewModel.uniqueDates.value?.let {
           ParentDatesAdapter(it, expensesList) { expenseId ->
               Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Clicked expense with id: $expenseId", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
       binding.rvParentExpenseDates.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } else {
       binding.rvParentExpenseDates.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}
```

**ExpenseEntity.kt**

```
@Entity(tableName = "expense-table")
data class ExpenseEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "date-time")
    val dateTime : Date?,
    val date : Date?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "account-type")
    val accountType : String = "",
    val category : String = "",
    val amount : Double = 0.0,
    val currency : String = "",
    val note : String = ""
```

)

Comment: What format is `Date` in? yyyy-MM-dd or something else?

Comment: @avalerio, it's in no format, it's of type Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations):

> These methods permit functional composition and delegation of LiveData
> instances. The transformations are calculated lazily, and will run
> only when the returned LiveData is observed. Lifecycle behavior is
> propagated from the input source LiveData to the returned one.

The issue here is that you never observe the transformed `LiveData` (`uniqueDates`) -- you only inspect the `value`, so the transformation is never applied.

One option, if you need both together, is to map into a joined view:

```
class MainActivityViewModel(private val expenseDao: ExpenseDao) : ViewModel() {
  val allExpenses : LiveData<List<ExpenseEntity>> =
    expenseDao.fetchAllExpenses().asLiveData()

  val allAndUniqueDatedExpenses: LiveData<Pair<List<ExpenseEntity>, List<Date>> = 
    Transformations.map(allExpenses) { expenses ->
      expenses to expenses.mapNotNull { it.date }.distinct()
    }
}
```

Then simply observe this joined value:

```
expensesViewModel.allAndUniqueDatedExpenses.observe(this) { (expenses, dates) ->
  binding.rvParentExpenseDates.adapter = 
    ParentDatesAdapter(dates, expenses) { expenseId ->
      Toast.makeText(...).show()
    }
}
```

However, I would argue here you don't really need another `LiveData` transformation. Simply do the transformation inline:

```
expensesViewModel.allExpenses.observe(this) { expenses ->
  val dates = expenses.mapNotNull { it.date }.distinct()

  binding.rvParentExpenseDates.adapter =
    ParentDatesAdapter(dates, expenses) { expenseId ->
      Toast.makeText(...).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin! Interesting about the pairing of LiveData, did not know that. But your simplier solution I guess is the one I should use :)